# Number of storms in a rainy season

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

This is a [follow-up to my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728494/conditioning-on-a-random-variable). Now instead of finding a probability I would like to **now find the expectation** too. I will restate the question and my solution below. I would appreciate if somebody could verify my work.

---

The number of storms in the upcoming rainy season is Poisson distributed but with a parameter value that is uniformly distributed between (0,5). That is Λ is uniformly distributed over (0,5), and given Λ = λ, the number of storms is Poisson with mean λ. Find the probability there are at least three storms this season.

**Probability:** 
By observation, we have
$$ P(X \geq 3) = 1-P(X<3) $$
By the definition of joint probability (of independent events) we have
$$ P(X \geq 3, \Lambda = \lambda ) = P( X \geq 3) P(\Lambda = \lambda), ~ \{\lambda ~ \epsilon ~ \Re\}$$

By independence of events, we have
$$ P( X \geq 3| \Lambda = \lambda ) =  P(X \geq 3), ~ \{\lambda ~ \epsilon ~ \Re\}$$
So what we want to find is the following for all $\lambda$ (i.e. condition on $\lambda$ and integrate)

$$1- \sum_{i=0}^{2} P(X=i, \Lambda = \lambda), ~~ \{\lambda ~ \epsilon ~ \Re\}$$ 
$$ = 1- \sum_{i=0}^{2}  \int_0^5  p(X=i|\Lambda = \lambda)f_\Lambda (\lambda)~d \lambda $$

Because $\Lambda$ is a uniform random variable, its probability density function is $\frac{1}{5}$ for all points on the interval [0,5] and zero elsewhere. So what we get is the following.

$$ = 1- \frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=0}^{2}  \int_0^5  \frac{e^{- \lambda}\lambda^i}{i!} d \lambda $$
After performing the above integration and summation, we are left with the following solution:
$$P(X \geq 3) = 1- \frac{1}{5} \left( (-e^{-5} + 1) + (1-6e^{-5}) + (2 - 37e^{-5}) \right)$$
$$ = 1 + \frac{1}{5} \left(   \frac{44}{e^{5}} - 4 \right) \approx 0.259294$$

---

**Expectation:**
We know that the sum of expectations is the expectation of sums
$$ E[X] =\sum_{all ~i}  E[X_i] $$
and that the mean of a Poisson random variable is $\lambda$

So in order to find the expected number of packet arrivals, we simply integrate $\lambda$ from 0 to 5 as follows.

$$E[X] = \int_0^5 \lambda ~d \lambda = \left[\frac{\lambda^2}{2} \right]_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda = 5} = \frac{25}{2} = 12.5$$

Comment: That's a lot of storms, particularly since worst case Poisson is $5$.

Comment: Yea, I didn't think the expectation looked quite right either

Comment: "By independence of events"... Ahem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation of $X$ is $E(E(X|\Lambda))$. The expectation of $X$ given 
$\Lambda=\lambda$ is $\lambda$. So we want
$$\int_0^5 \lambda\cdot\frac{1}{5}\,d\lambda.$$